# Cortana does not create reminders from Text Messages

Tags: windows-10-mobile, cortana

Is it me or Cortana is no longer read the information from the text messages to automatically suggest to create reminders?

In Windows 8.1 Cortana would notice that the text messages have some sort of schedule info. The time would be highlighted with a sort of pseudo-hyperlink. You could just click on a pseudo-hyperlink in the text messages to create the reminders from the context information from the text messages. See [this article](http://www.windowscentral.com/cortana-scheduling-windows-phone-81) for more information.

[image: Cortana]

It worked for me when I was on WP8.1. Id does not work with Windows 10bile 10.

Does it work for anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does work in Windows 10 Mobile, depending on your region settings. When I click a date in a text message, Outlook Calendar opens and the title, date and time is pre-filled.

Comment: I am glad it works for you. It definitely does not work for me. I guess it is not available in Australia. Cortana works here, it is just the reminders feature that doesn't

Comment: @cha then it seems like it has to do with your phones/Cortanas region.

Comment: @cha just realized I haven't seen it for very long now :O